# Unable to render image which has a space in the url

Tags: html, jsf

```
<h:graphicImage value="/sky blue/img/logo.png"/>
```

Unable to render the above image which has a space in the URL, how should I encode the space between "sky" and "blue"

Comment: My wild uninformed guess is to try %20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spaces in URIs must be represented as `%20` (or `+` in form encoded data)

Answer (score 2):

Try: `value="/sky%20blue/img/logo.png"`